# PHP Notice: Функция register_rest_route вызвана неправильно. Пространства имен не должны начинаться или заканчиваться символом слэша

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нашел код, на который ссылается дебаггер, но никак не могу понять что в нем не так. Подскажите кто может разобраться.

> Notice: Функция register_rest_route вызвана **неправильно**. Пространства имен не должны начинаться или заканчиваться символом слэша.

```
// Register our routes.
public function register_routes() {

    $endpoints = $this->get_endpoints();

    foreach ( $endpoints as $endpoint ) {

        $args = array(
            'methods'             => $endpoint->get_method(),
            'callback'            => array( $endpoint, 'callback' ),
            'permission_callback' => array( $endpoint, 'permission_callback' ),
        );

        $endpoint_args = $endpoint->get_args();

        if ( ! empty( $endpoint_args ) ) {
            $args['args'] = $endpoint->get_args();
        }

        $route = '/' . $endpoint->get_name() . '/' . $endpoint->get_query_params();

        register_rest_route( $this->api_namespace, $route, $args );//вот на эту строку ссылается дебаггер
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё же написано. Уберите в предыдущей строчке слеш в начале выражения.

Comment: даже в примере(https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_rest_route) во втором передаваемом элементе слеш нужен, ошибка в чем то другом

Comment: Да, точно. Ведь ошибка говорит о namespace

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно заменить последнюю строку на это:

```
$fixed_namespace = (substr($this->api_namespace,0,1)=='/')? substr($this->api_namespace,1):$this->api_namespace;
register_rest_route( $fixed_namespace, $route, $args );
```

Comment: Проще использовать ltrim(). А ещё лучше, поправить свойство $this->api_namespace в том месте, где оно определяется.